# What do you call a sentence that reverses parts of the first clause in a second clause that makes sense, too?

Tags: meaning, sentence, sentence-patterns, rhetorical-devices

I'm looking for the definition of a phrase like this, where two ideas of thought are reversed and still make sense.

> Nothing too exciting to report, but reporting nonetheless is exciting.

I feel like sentences like this should have a proper name.

Comment: ***Wordplay**?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. The phrase is actually called an [antimetabole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole), defined by Wikipedia as:

> the repetition of words in successive clauses, but in transposed order (e.g., "I know what I like, and I like what I know").

Comment: +1 I was going to say *chiasmus* (having lived through Latin and Greek in high school [during the dark ages]) but on deeper reflection, you are more right!